# Is it possible to pass a modified request from middleware to subsequent routes in Next.js 13.4 App Route version?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm working on a Next.js project using the App Route version 13.4. In this version, I'm using the App Route module to define my routes and handle requests. I have a middleware function that modifies the incoming request, and I want to pass this modified request to the subsequent routes.

Here is an example of my middleware function:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { UserAdminInfo, UserPortalInfo } from "./app/libs/types";
import { hasPermission } from "./app/helpers/roles";

type User = UserAdminInfo | UserPortalInfo;

export interface CustomNextRequest extends NextRequest {
  originalUrl: string;
  locals: {
    user?: User;
  };
}

// CREATE MIDDLEWARE TO CHECK IF USER IS AUTHENTICATED
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/api/admin/:path*", "/api/usersales/:path*"],
};

export default async function middleware(request: CustomNextRequest) {
  // Initialize the locals object if it doesn't exist
  if (!request.locals) {
    request.locals = {};
  }

  // FIND TOKEN IN REQUEST HEADER AND CHECK IF USER EXISTS
  const token = request.headers.get("authorization");
  if (!token) {
    return NextResponse.json({
      error: "Not authorized",
    });
  }

  // Retrieve the user type from the request header
  const userType = request.headers.get("User-Type");

  // Check if the user type is valid
  if (userType !== "admin" && userType !== "userportal") {
    console.log("Invalid user type at middleware");
    return NextResponse.json({
      error: "Invalid user type at middleware",
    });
  }

  // Extract the intended endpoint from the URL
  const intendedEndpoint = request.nextUrl.pathname;
  console.log(intendedEndpoint);

  // Make a request to the check-token API route to verify the token.
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/checktoken", {
    headers: {
      authorization: token,
      "User-Type": userType,
    },
  });

  // Check the response status
  if (!response.ok) {
    const error = await response.json();
    return NextResponse.json(error);
  }

  // Parse the response JSON data.
  const user = await response.json();

  if (!user) {
    return NextResponse.json({
      error: "Access denied for this endpoint",
    });
  }

  const hasAccess = hasPermission(user.role, intendedEndpoint);
  console.log(hasAccess);
  if (!hasAccess) {
    return NextResponse.json({
      error: "Access denied for this endpoint",
    });
  }

  // Store the user object in request.locals for access in the route handler.
 request.locals.user = user.user;



  // If the middleware execution reaches this point, it means the token is valid and user type is valid.
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

also Here is an example of one of my subsequent routes:

```
import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismadb";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { User } from "@/app/libs/types";
import { CustomNextRequest } from "@/middleware";

export async function PUT(
  request: CustomNextRequest,
  { params: { id } }: { params: { id: string } },
) {
  if (request.locals.user) {
    console.log(request.locals.user);
  }

  try {
    // Update the user by setting isactive to false
    const updatedUser = await prisma.userPortalInfo.update({
      where: { id: id },
      data: {
        isactive: false,
      },
    });

    return NextResponse.json(updatedUser);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({
      error: "Internal server error",
    });
  }
}
```

In this route, I'm trying to access the modified request's user object using request.locals.user. However, I'm getting an undefined error when I try to console log it.

I would like to know how I can access the modified request in my subsequent routes and resolve the issue of the user object being undefined. How can I ensure that the modifications made in the middleware are passed and accessible in the subsequent routes?

I encountered a situation where I needed to optimize my Next.js 13.4 App Route version project by minimizing redundant API calls in the subsequent routes. To achieve this, I implemented a middleware function that modified the incoming request. Within this middleware, I created a custom request object and added a locals object to store additional data. Specifically, I added a key called user to store the user object obtained from another API.

The purpose of storing the user object in the modified request was to provide the subsequent routes easy access to the user's data and avoid unnecessary API calls. However, I faced a challenge when attempting to retrieve the user key in the subsequent routes using request.locals.user. It resulted in an undefined error, preventing me from utilizing the user's data as intended.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to successfully access the modified request's user object within the subsequent routes. My goal is to leverage the user's data available in the middleware and reduce the need for additional fetching in the subsequent routes. Thank you in advance for your assistance and expertise.

Comment: I know this is possible with Express.js, but not sure Next.js allows it.